# Linked list using class and friend functions: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list, friend-function

I am unable to find the reason for the segmentation fault. I would really appreciate your help in any ways. Thanking you in advance.

/*A rudimentary linked list for implementing polynomials.
    This is just an experiment as I have no experience with linked lists*/

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class linked_list
{
 //First element will hold index of the polynomial and the second element will hold its coefficient
int a[2];
linked_list *p;

 public:
  linked_list()              //Constructor to initialize to zero
  {
    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=0;
    p=NULL;
  }

  friend int start(linked_list *obj1)
  {
    cout<<"Enter the index and coeff of the polynomial:\n";
    cin>>obj1->a[0];     //Accepting the values of index and coeff
    cin>>obj1->a[1];   
    linked_list *obj2;   
    int garbage;         //A garbage just to hold the return value 
    char c;
    cout<<"Enter y to continue or n to discontinue:\n";
    cin>>c;
     if(c=='y')
     {
      obj1->p=obj2;   //Setting pointer of first node to point to the second
      garbage=start(obj2);
      return garbage;
     }
     else
     {
      obj1->p=NULL;  //Setting last pointer to NULL
      return 0;
     }
 }

  friend void print(linked_list *obj1)
 {
   linked_list *temp;                 //Temporary object pointer
   cout<<obj1->a[0]<<"x^"<<obj1->a[1];
   temp=obj1;                         
   while(temp->p!=NULL)
     {
      temp=temp->p;                  //Temporary object pointer now holds address of next location
      cout<<"+"<<temp->a[0]<<"x^"<<temp->a[1];
     }
 }
};
int main()
{
  int garbage;
  linked_list *obj1;
  garbage=start(obj1);
  print(obj1);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

Enter the index and coeff of the polynomial:

0

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It just accepts one element(index) and terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an uninitialized pointer. You need to acquire some memory either with new or put it on the stack:

Heap:

```
linked_list *obj1 = new linked_list;
```

Stack:

```
linked_list obj1;
garbage=start(&obj1);
```